# How to remove QEMU completely

Tags: uninstall, qemu

I installed QEMU from software center but removed latter (using software center). But updates are recommended to QEMU (see screen shot). That means QEMU is not uninstalled properly. How can I completely remove QEMU from my computer?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the Terminal


Uninstall just qemu with 


 
`sudo apt-get remove qemu`


Uninstall qemu and it's dependencies with this


`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove qemu`


If you want to purge all the config and data off the system you can also use


`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove qemu`


Source::[Installion.co.uk](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/q/qemu/uninstall/index.html)

Comment: This just worked for me. Where did you find this documentation?

Comment: @DUKE I added the source in the answer. I did a simple google search to find it

Comment: I still see a bunch of `qemu` packages installed on my machine (using synaptic) like: `qemu-kvm`, `qemu-system-*`, etc